# MySQLi update prepared statement not updating database

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli, prepared-statement

So I have this update statement which when I dump the $_POST variables., I get the outputs I want.

```
 $stmt = $dbConnectionW->prepare("UPDATE members SET 
                          fname='". mysqli_real_escape_string($dbConnectionW, $_POST['fname']) ."',
                          sname='". mysqli_real_escape_string($dbConnectionW, $_POST['sname']) ."',
                          gender='". mysqli_real_escape_string($dbConnectionW, $_POST['gender']) ."',
                          nationality='". mysqli_real_escape_string($dbConnectionW, $_POST['nation']) ."',
                          year='". mysqli_real_escape_string($dbConnectionW, $_POST['year']) ."',
                          dep1='". mysqli_real_escape_string($dbConnectionW, $_POST['dep1']) ."',
                          dep2='". mysqli_real_escape_string($dbConnectionW, $_POST['dep2']) ."',
                          f_pos='". mysqli_real_escape_string($dbConnectionW, $_POST['f_pos']) ."',
                          f_region='". mysqli_real_escape_string($dbConnectionW, $_POST['f_region']) ."',
                          exp_comp='".$comp."',
                          exp_dep='".$comp_dep."',
                          shareinfo='".$shareinfo."',
                          interest='".$interest."',
                          userconfirm = '1'
                              WHERE confirmcode = '".$passkey."';");
              $stmt->execute(); 
              if (!$stmt)
              {
              die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($dbConnectionW));
              }
              $smst-> close(); }}} mysqli_close($dbConnectionW);
      }
```

Basically the issue is that it won't update the database! It works with no errors, but the database does not get updated after this sql/php attempt.

Can anyone see anything wrong with my code? What are some possible causes for why my would my database not be updated? I've been starting at this for the past hour.

Comment: Are you sure that the value of `$passKey` is correct? Are you sure you're commit the transaction?

Comment: You don't need to escape your variables in a prepared statement, instead you should bind your variables before executing the statement.

Comment: $passkey is definitely correct, just checked it and tried finding user with an email too. Also I binded my variables above this code but didn't show it here.

Comment: You binded above this code? You should prepare the statement and then bind the variables.

Comment: you should echo the query before you run and see if it makes sense. try running that directly and see if does what you expect

Comment: Actually sorry, no binding done. Binded some variables but they arent used in the update. What do u mean by echo the query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to escape your variables in a prepared statement, instead you should bind your variables before executing the statement. Also the column names should be inside ` marks.

```
$stmt = $dbConnectionW->prepare("UPDATE members SET 
                      `fname`=?,
                      `sname`=?,
                      `gender`=?,
                      `nationality`=?,
                      `year`=?,
                      `dep1`=?,
                      `dep2`=?,
                      `f_pos`=?,
                      `f_region`=?,
                      `exp_comp`=?,
                      `exp_dep`=?,
                      `shareinfo`=?,
                      `interest`=?,
                      `userconfirm`=?
                          WHERE `confirmcode`=?");
$stmt->bind_param('ssssissssssssis',$_POST['fname'],$_POST['sname'],$_POST['gender'],...);          
$stmt->execute();
```

I haven't included all the bound parameters for brevity.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It worked, you are my light and my savior. Thank you