# mysqli not updating database

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to convert my site to mysqli and I cannot get the databse to update or the results to show on the site. Also, the page is not redirecting, it is just showing a blank EditPost.php page

If you could please advise to what I could be doing wrong I would greatly appreciate it.

EditPost.php

```
   <?php

    $db = new mysqli("localhost","admin","password","database"); 

    if(!$db) {
    die('sorry we are having some problbems');
}

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $id = $_POST['EditID'];
    $itemname = $_POST['itemname'];
    $manufacture = $_POST['manufacture'];
    $model = $_POST['model'];
    $serial = $_POST['serial'];
    $year = $_POST['year'];
    $condition = $_POST['condition'];
    $category = $_POST['category'];
    $desc = $_POST['desc'];
    $dimension = $_POST['dimensions'];
    $location = $_POST['location'];
    $price = $_POST['price'];
    $purchase = $_POST['purchase'];
    $addedby = $_POST['addedby'];
    $notes = $_POST['notes'];
    $ran = $_POST['ran'];
    $electrical = $_POST['electrical'];
    $owner = $_POST['owner'];
    $featured = $_POST['featured'];
    $showmanu = $_POST['showmanu'];
    $showmodel = $_POST['showmodel'];
    $showserial = $_POST['showserial'];
    $showyear = $_POST['showyear'];
    $showdem = $_POST['showdem'];
    $showelec = $_POST['showelec'];
    $showran = $_POST['showran'];
    $showloca = $_POST['showloca'];
    $showown = $_POST['showown'];
    $showpur = $_POST['showpur'];
    $showsale = $_POST['showsale'];

    $query = "UPDATE new_equip SET `itemname`=?, `manufacture`=?, `model`=?, `serial`=?, `year`=?, `condition`=?, `category`=?, `desc`=?, `dimension`=?, `location`=?, `price`=?, `purchase`=?, `addedby`=?, `notes`=?, `ran`=?, `electrical`=?, `owner`=?, `featured`=?, `showmanu`=?, `showmodel`=?, `showserial`=?, `showyear`=?, `showdem`=?, `showelec`=?, `showran`=?, `showloca`=?, `showown`=?, `showpur`=?, `showsale`=? WHERE id=?  LIMIT 1";
    $conn = $db->prepare($query);
    $conn->bind_param("sssssssssssssssssiiiiiiiiiiiii", $_POST['item'], $_POST['manufacture'], $_POST['model'], $_POST['serial'], $_POST['year'], $_POST['condition'], $_POST['category'], $_POST['desc'], $_POST['dimension'], $_POST['location'], $_POST['price'], $_POST['purchase'], $_POST['addedby'], $_POST['notes'], $_POST['ran'], $_POST['electrical'], $_POST['owner'], $_POST['featured'], $_POST['showmanu'], $_POST['showmodel'], $_POST['showserial'], $_POST['showyear'], $_POST['showdem'], $_POST['showelec'], $_POST['showran'], $_POST['showloca'], $_POST['showown'], $_POST['showpur'], $_POST['showsale']);

    if(!$conn->execute()){trigger_error("there was an error....".$db->error, E_USER_WARNING);}
    header('location: inventory.php?Msg=Update');

    $db->close();
        }

    ?>
```

Part of my form

```
<form method="post" action="EditPost.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-horizontal" accept-charset="UTF-8">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-3">Item ID</label>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <input type="text" name="EditID" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" class="form-control" />
        </div> <!-- /.col -->
    </div> <!-- /.form-group -->

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-3">Item Name</label>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <input type="text" name="itemname" value="<?php echo $row['itemname']; ?>" class="form-control" />
        </div> <!-- /.col -->
    </div> <!-- /.form-group -->

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-3">Manufacture</label>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <input type="text" name="manufacture" value="<?php echo $row['manufacture']; ?>" class="form-control" />
        </div> <!-- /.col -->
        <input type="checkbox" name="showmanu" value="1" <?php echo ($row['showmanu'] == 1) ? 'checked="checked"' : ''; ?> />
        <span style="float:right; font-size: 10px; margin-top: 4px">Check to show</span>
    </div> <!-- /.form-group -->
```

This is the tutorial I was trying to follow.
http://coderlearner.com/PHP_MySQLi_Example_Update_Record

After doing some searching on the board, I found a thread that shows a different "$query". Would this be what I would have to use?

```
$query = "UPDATE new_equip SET `itemname`=?, `manufacture`=?, `model`=?, `showmanu`=?, `showmodel`=?, `showserial`=? WHERE `id`=?  LIMIT 1";
$conn = $db->prepare($query);
$conn->bind_param('sssiii', $_POST['item'], $_POST['manufacture'], $_POST['model'], $_POST['showmanu'], $_POST['showmodel'], $_POST['showserial']);
```

Comment: You have 7 parameters, but only 6 letters in `sssiii`. You need a type letter for each parameter.

Comment: You only need backticks around a column name if it contains special characters or is a reserved word.

Comment: Also `if ($conn->execute())` using the wrong variable. @Barmar

Comment: @Fred-ii- It's the right variable, just poorly named.

Comment: @Barmar Ah ok. I see it now; *confusing*.

Comment: Replace `if ($conn->execute()) {...}` with `if(!$conn->execute()){trigger_error("there was an error....".$db->error, E_USER_WARNING);}` to get the real reason why your code is failing. Plus, it's best to use `if(isset($_POST['submit']))` instead of `if ($_POST['submit'])`. http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php will tell you if there are any other errors.

Comment: Plus, a possible missing `</form>` tag. It's not in your question. Error reporting should throw back a few notices.

Comment: I just changed this and nothing happened, just a blank EditPost.php as for the </form> I just posted the top of the form.

Comment: If you have more code / form inputs, you'll need to modify your question. Also, if your code does have the missing `</form>` tag, add that too. Your question is unclear. In the meantime that you'll be doing that, Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.

Comment: So, you've added more PHP/SQL. What about the HTML form with the related inputs to match? Plus, what did error checking tell you? Surely, something must've come about.

Comment: The html form has the correct fields. I added the error code, but it just shows the blank EditPost.php page. No syntax error.

Comment: Does your submit first have a name attribute to go with `if(isset($_POST['submit']))`? If you're using anything other than `<input type="submit" name="submit">` then your code will do nothing. You don't have enough of your HTML form in your question for us to help you any further. You will need to go over that tutorial once again and double check all your inputs whether they contain typos, hold the right name attribute, letter case, etc.

Comment: Yes my submit has the name="submit"

Comment: What I suggest you do: Start by using 2-3 POST and values at the max then build up from there. You've put all these ingredients into a soup that you hope will come out tasting like what Momma used to make; not good. You're assuming success right away without taking failure into account which may come as a pleasant surprise. Your question is a debugging one and is out of the scope of Stack's questions. Good luck, I wish you well, *cheers*

Comment: I appreciate it. I will start small and build from there. I just jumped right into it. One must learn to crawl before he can walk right.

Comment: *That's the spirit!* Best to build a house brick by brick, rather than wait for it to fall on you like a *ton of bricks*; oucher! You'll get there, *trust me on this*. Enjoy the ride. P.s.: Even I still build "houses" brick-by-brick.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a character in the types string for the `$id` parameter. It should be:

```
$conn->bind_param("sssiiii", $item, $manufacture, $model, $showmanu, $showmodel, $showserial, $id);
```

There needs to be a type letter for each parameter. Since you have 7 parameters, there must be 7 types.

Also, since your form uses `name="EditID"` for the Item ID field, you need to use:

```
$id = $_POST['EditID'];
```

to match it.

Comment: OP has `$_POST['id']` and using `name="EditID"` and possibly a missing closing `</form>` tag which isn't in their code.

Comment: He said it's "part of my form", so I guess he just copied the beginning of the form. But the wrong name does look like a real error.

Comment: You know as well as I, that OP's often either leave out certain parts of code, or haven't their proper tags closed in production code. Anything can happen ;-) but this will get them going for sure.

Comment: Ok, I changed this $id = $_POST['EditID']; but it still isnt updating. Just refreshing to a blank EditPost.php

Comment: If you're getting a blank page, there's probably a syntax error somewhere. Check your PHP error log.

Comment: *Hm...* having gone over OP's code again; they're only showing us 4 inputs, as opposed to 6 in their values. Their name attributes in what they've shown us doesn't match many of their POST arrays.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Other than EditID, which names don't match?

Comment: `$_POST['item']` and `name="itemname"` unless there are 2 other inputs they're not showing us. Plus no reference for `$_POST['showmodel'], $_POST['showserial']`

Comment: I just edited my code per advice of users. It is my entire code. I was using a snippet just to see what I was doing wrong.

Comment: @Fred-ii- The code says `$itemname = $_POST['itemname'];`. I'm ignoring the alternate version at the end of the post.

Comment: The OP's added more PHP/SQL, but not the related HTML inputs to go with them. I've asked the OP what errors they're getting, which they should be getting. Time will tell.

Comment: @WebbieWorks Why have you assigned all those variables from `$_POST`, but then used `$_POST` in the `bind_param` call? Some of the parameter names are wrong there.

Comment: You're missing `$_POST['ItemID']` in the `bind_param` arguments.

Comment: I followed this [Stack Thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27884296/mysqli-update-prepared-statement-not-updating-database)  for the bind_param. [I am brand new to mysqli so I wanted to look for an answer before I asked.

Comment: That's fine. But if you're going to do that, why do you bother setting all those variables that you don't use? And you still need to make sure you have all the parameters that are needed.

Comment: It doesn't matter whether you use `$id` or `$_POST['ItemID']`. A variable is a variable.

Comment: forgive me if this seems like a stupid question, What do you mean "setting all the variables I dont use"? and by parameters, you mean the "ssii" section, yes I double checked that they correspond with the code.

Comment: I mean the assignments like `$id = $_POST['EditID']`.

Comment: Your edit has 30 letters in the first argument, but there are only 29 parameters after that. You're missing `$_POST['EditID']` at the end.

Comment: Correct, I fixed that.  I am going to take Fred ii advice and start small. Go with 5-6 Post and grow from there. I think I took on to much trying to learn. Just wanting to get my site changed over because of all the suggestions of the users here. I appreciate your help.